# Compare two DirectoryInfo and remove from A where B Exists. LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, directoryinfo

I'm trying to remove from DirectoryInfo dInfoA where dInfoA has Directories that are listed in dInfoB.

```
DirectoryInfo Dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Apples");
DirectoryInfo[] dInfoA = Dinfo.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


DirectoryInfo DinfoB = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Apples\Oranges");
DirectoryInfo[] dInfoB = DinfoB.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The folder structure is this:

C:\apples
C:\apples\oranges
C:\apples\banannas

I want to take the directory info from A and B and remove C:\Apples\Oranges from A because it exists B.

Is there a way to do this in LINQ, or a way to do this at all?

Comment: `GetDirectories` won't get the root directory itself. It's not simply about Linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done simply enough.  Create a set (that can be much more efficiently searched than a `List` or array) of all of the paths in the second directory.  Then you can easily write a query to give you all of the items where the directory path is in that set (or not in that set, if that's what you want).  Note the Comparer is passed to the set to ensure it does a case insensitive comparison.

```
var directoryBPaths = new HashSet<string>(dInfoB.Select(dir => dir.FullName),
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

var directoriesToRemove = dInfoA.Where(dir => 
    directoryBPaths.Contains(dir.FullName));

//If you just want a sequence of the items not 
//in the other set, get that directly
var directoriesToKeep = dInfoA.Where(dir => 
    !directoryBPaths.Contains(dir.FullName));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is this different from my answer? Except works with a hashset internally.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Very minimally.  It's virtually identical to the use of `ExceptBy` except that it doesn't rely on an external dependency that the OP clearly has trouble understanding.  As to your second solution, it adds a fair bit of overhead (as I've described to you in the past) due to repeated calling of the selector.  It's also complex enough that the OP may have trouble understanding what's going on.  The answers are fundamentally very similar in how they work though; there's no doubt about that.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance And the amount of code, also. It's cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen anything faster in my whole miserable life. Just kidding, this is a touch of an experienced programmer. Nice work.

Comment: @AndreCalil I doubt 10 lines would be troublesome to maintain.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Mostly what it comes down to is whether or not you're going to be using it just this once, or whether or not this is the type of operation that you do often enough for it to be worth the overhead of learning and maintaining utility methods such as those in MoreLINQ.  If you are willing to really learn how they work, include them in your project, keep them up to date, etc. then they're a net win.  If not, the overhead of using them just occasionally may not warrant doing all of that.  I would use MoreLINQ, but I recognize that it may not be appropriate for the OP.

Comment: @Servy I tried to use the following to remove items from dInfoA however the items remain.  What am I missing?

 foreach(var dtRemove in directoriesToRemove)
                            {

                                directories.ToList().Remove(dtRemove);
                            }

Comment: @Mike You're creating an entirely new list, based off of the item in `cirectories`, removing the items from that list, and then throwing that list away.  If you just want a new list with all of the items not in the other set, then just add a `!` to the `Where` clause to get the items not in the set.  Much easier (and more efficient) than removing all of the items from the list.

Comment: @servy i'm not the best with linq, and such a foolish question probably but where is the ! applied, the problem is i'm not sure how to take the directoriesToRemove to actually remove then from dInfoA

Comment: @Mike I put it in an edit, but as I specifically said, you don't need to remove anything from the list.  Just create a brand new collection.  It will be easier and faster.  Removing items from a list is not an efficient operation, especially if you want to remove a large number of them.

Comment: @Servy how do you exclude the root directory?

Comment: @Mike Add an appropriate `Where` clause when constructing `dInfoA` and `dInfoAB` that excludes the root.  Or just add it to the end, if you prefer.

Comment: @Servy var AllDirectoryPaths = directories.Where(dir => !directoryBPaths.Contains(dir.FullName)).Where(dir => !directoryBPaths.Contains(@"C:\Apples\Oranges")); ?

Comment: @Mike you're over-complicating it.  `Where(dir => dir.FullName != DinfoB.FullName)`  Or, if that's what you want, you could just add `DinfoB.FullName` to the `HashSet` right after creating it; that would have the same effect (and be much more efficient in retrospect).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and `ExceptBy`:

```
dInfoB = dInfoB.ExceptBy(dInfoA, n => n.FullName, 
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray();
```

If you don't have access to MoreLINQ, you could also use this (slightly) less efficient way:

```
dInfoB = dInfoB.Except(dInfoA, 
    PropertyEqualityComparer.GetNew<DirectoryInfo, string>
    (n => n.FullName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
```

Still a lot more efficient than `Where` + `Any`.

if I get what you're trying to do. The extra comparer is because DirectoryInfo decides that it doesn't want to override `Equals`.

The comparer is this:

```
public class PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty> 
    : IEqualityComparer<TObject>
{
    Func<TObject, TProperty> _selector;
    IEqualityComparer<TProperty> _internalComparer;
    public PropertyEqualityComparer(Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> innerEqualityComparer = null)
    {
        _selector = propertySelector;
        _internalComparer = innerEqualityComparer;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(TObject obj)
    {
        return _selector(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
    public bool Equals(TObject x, TObject y)
    {
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> comparer = 
            _internalComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default;
        return comparer.Equals(_selector(x), _selector(y));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it won't. It will return all `dInfoB` contents as the files are from different directories.

Comment: I think he's saying it should be `dInfoA = dInfoA.Except(dInfoB)...`, since the OP wants to remove the entries in B from A...

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic You're right, it (basically) uses ReferenceEquals... fixing.

Comment: Now, completely fixed. Should be.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Where is LINQ?

Comment: @BhushanFirake I'm assuming you mean MoreLINQ, and if you click on the word on my post you can get it. Alternatively, you could type `install-package MoreLINQ` into NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

`GetDirectories` won't get the base directory, so `B` would be empty.
You must add the root so you can achieve your goal.

Check this out:

```
  DirectoryInfo rootA = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Apples");
  List<DirectoryInfo> listA = rootA.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
  listA.Add(rootA);

  DirectoryInfo rootB = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Apples\Oranges");
  List<DirectoryInfo> listB = rootB.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
  listB.Add(rootB);

  DirectoryInfo[] aDiffB = listA.Where(x => !listB.Any(y => string.Equals(y.FullName, x.FullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).ToArray();
```

Comment: It's a bit pointless to add the root to then remove it. Also, why the ToUpperInvariant?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance He should be using `string.Equals(a,b,StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`, that method is a less desirable way of trying to achieve case insensitivity.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance It's not, because that's what the OP wants. There may have case variances with the directory name (I've tested it myself), that's why I'm putting the strings with the same case to test them.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance That's easy to say after Servy's comment, right? You got the point, anyway.

Comment: @AndreCalil I didn't even know it was there.

Comment: note that this answer, like Nikolas, is needlessly inefficient due to the fact that lists can't be efficiently searched.  Just using an appropriate data structure, such as a `HashSet` can dramatically increase performance with very little added effort on your part.

Comment: @Servy Indeed, I wasn't worried with performance when I posted the answer.